# External monitor not working

Tags: nvidia, hdmi, monitor

I have a dual-boot (Windows 10) Acer Aspire A715-71G Notebook with an Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile GPU and I am trying to connect it with additional monitors to extend the view. When I plug in the HDMI cable of the additional monitor to my laptop and restart my computer, the additional monitor works perfectly until I enter my password. After I enter my desktop, the additional monitor stops working. Inside the Displays menu, no additional monitor can be found or selected.

Further system info:

1. 18.04.1-Ubuntu
2. 5.3.0-53-generic
3. x86_64
4. NVIDIA-SMI 440.26   |    Driver Version: 440.26

Thank you for your time

---

```
$ xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
```

```
[     4.911] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     4.911] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-148-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[     4.911] Current Operating System: Linux ntelo-ubuntu 5.3.0-53-generic #47~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 7 13:10:50 UTC 2020 x86_64
[     4.911] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-53-generic root=UUID=c5036a4f-9146-4382-be4f-313a205c567e ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[     4.911] Build Date: 02 May 2019  08:06:54AM
[     4.911] xorg-server-hwe-18.04 2:1.20.4-1ubuntu3~18.04.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[     4.911] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[     4.911]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     4.911] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     4.912] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Jul  4 21:34:44 2020
[     4.912] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     4.913] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[     4.913] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[     4.913] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[     4.913] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[     4.914] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[     4.914] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     4.914] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     4.914] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[     4.914] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[     4.914] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[     4.914] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     4.914]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     4.914] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[     4.914]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     4.914] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[     4.914]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     4.914] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[     4.914]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     4.914] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[     4.914]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     4.914] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[     4.914] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     4.914] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[     4.914] (II) Loader magic: 0x56097ec15020
[     4.914] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     4.914]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     4.914]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[     4.914]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[     4.914]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[     4.914] (++) using VT number 7

[     4.914] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[     4.915] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[     4.961] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[     4.974] (**) OutputClass "nvidia" ModulePath extended to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     4.974] (**) OutputClass "Nvidia Prime" ModulePath extended to "/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     4.974] (**) OutputClass "Nvidia Prime" setting /dev/dri/card1 as PrimaryGPU
[     4.975] (--) PCI: (0@0:2:0) 8086:591b:1025:119b rev 4, Mem @ 0xa2000000/16777216, 0xb0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00005000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[     4.976] (--) PCI:*(1@0:0:0) 10de:1c8d:1025:1197 rev 161, Mem @ 0xa3000000/16777216, 0x90000000/268435456, 0xa0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00004000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[     4.976] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     4.976] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     4.982] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.983]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     4.983]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[     4.983] (II) Applying OutputClass "nvidia" to /dev/dri/card1
[     4.983]    loading driver: nvidia
[     4.983] (II) Applying OutputClass "Nvidia Prime" to /dev/dri/card1
[     4.983]    loading driver: nvidia
[     5.243] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[     5.243] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[     5.243] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[     5.243] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[     5.243] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[     5.243] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[     5.243] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[     5.243] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/nvidia_drv.so
[     5.248] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     5.248]    compiled for 1.6.99.901, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.248]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     5.248] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[     5.249] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[     5.251] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.251]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.16
[     5.251]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     5.251]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[     5.251] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[     5.251] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[     5.251] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.251]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.20.4
[     5.251]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     5.251]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[     5.251] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[     5.251] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[     5.252] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.252]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 0.5.0
[     5.252]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     5.252]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[     5.252] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     5.252] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[     5.252] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.252]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 2.4.0
[     5.252]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     5.252]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[     5.253] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  440.26  Sun Oct 13 17:46:52 UTC 2019
[     5.253] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[     5.253] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Mon Jan 28 23:25:58 2019 -0500
[     5.253] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[     5.253]    RIVA TNT            (NV04)
[     5.253]    RIVA TNT2           (NV05)
[     5.253]    GeForce 256         (NV10)
[     5.253]    GeForce 2           (NV11, NV15)
[     5.253]    GeForce 4MX         (NV17, NV18)
[     5.253]    GeForce 3           (NV20)
[     5.253]    GeForce 4Ti         (NV25, NV28)
[     5.253]    GeForce FX          (NV3x)
[     5.253]    GeForce 6           (NV4x)
[     5.253]    GeForce 7           (G7x)
[     5.253]    GeForce 8           (G8x)
[     5.253]    GeForce 9           (G9x)
[     5.253]    GeForce GTX 2xx/3xx (GT2xx)
[     5.253]    GeForce GTX 4xx/5xx (GFxxx)
[     5.253]    GeForce GTX 6xx/7xx (GKxxx)
[     5.253]    GeForce GTX 9xx     (GMxxx)
[     5.253]    GeForce GTX 10xx    (GPxxx)
[     5.254] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[     5.254] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[     5.254] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[     5.254] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[     5.254] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[     5.254] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[     5.255] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.255]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.255]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     5.255] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[     5.255] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[     5.255] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[     5.256] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.256]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.256]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     5.256] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[     5.256] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[     5.256] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[     5.257] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[     5.273] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[     5.273] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[     5.273] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     5.273] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[     5.274] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.274]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 0.0.2
[     5.274]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[     5.289] (II) modeset(G0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[     5.290] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[     5.290] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[     5.290] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[     5.290] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     5.290] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[     5.290] (II) Applying OutputClass "nvidia" options to /dev/dri/card1
[     5.290] (II) Applying OutputClass "Nvidia Prime" options to /dev/dri/card1
[     5.290] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
[     5.290] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
[     5.290] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[     5.290] (II) Loading sub module "glxserver_nvidia"
[     5.290] (II) LoadModule: "glxserver_nvidia"
[     5.290] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/libglxserver_nvidia.so
[     5.324] (II) Module glxserver_nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     5.324]    compiled for 1.6.99.901, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.324]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     5.324] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  440.26  Sun Oct 13 17:44:48 UTC 2019
[     5.326] (II) NVIDIA: The X server does not support PRIME Render Offload.
[     5.327] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-0 at PCI:1:0:0
[     5.327] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0 (boot)
[     5.327] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GTX 1050 (GP107-A) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[     5.327] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 2097152 kBytes
[     5.327] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 86.07.40.00.12
[     5.327] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[     5.357] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics M2255 (DFP-0): connected
[     5.357] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics M2255 (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
[     5.357] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics M2255 (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     5.357] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     5.361] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[     5.361] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[     5.361] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[     5.361] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[     5.362] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[     5.362] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[     5.362] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1920 x 1080
[     5.367] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (92, 91); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[     5.367] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[     5.368] (==) modeset(G0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[     5.368] (==) modeset(G0): RGB weight 888
[     5.368] (==) modeset(G0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     5.368] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[     5.368] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[     5.368] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[     5.374] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.374]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.1
[     5.374]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     5.431] (II) modeset(G0): glamor X acceleration enabled on Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 630 (Kaby Lake GT2) 
[     5.431] (II) modeset(G0): glamor initialized
[     5.432] (II) modeset(G0): Output eDP-1-1 has no monitor section
[     5.433] (II) modeset(G0): EDID for output eDP-1-1
[     5.433] (II) modeset(G0): Manufacturer: CMN  Model: 15d5  Serial#: 0
[     5.433] (II) modeset(G0): Year: 2015  Week: 38
[     5.433] (II) modeset(G0): EDID Version: 1.4
[     5.433] (II) modeset(G0): Digital Display Input
[     5.433] (II) modeset(G0): 6 bits per channel
[     5.433] (II) modeset(G0): Digital interface is DisplayPort
[     5.433] (II) modeset(G0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 34  vert.: 19
...
```

Comment: Could you open a terminal and add the output of `xrandr`? For this [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1256377/edit) your question and paste the contents into it. (use the `{}` button to format the pasted text. In addition, the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` would be interesting

Comment: The log file was extremely large and couldn't be posted complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[     5.432] (II) modeset(G0): Output eDP-1-1 has no monitor section`
You are using nvidia and wayland (instead of the X-Server). Xorg recognizes your second screen, but can't do anything with it because wayland controls it.

There might be a wayland solution I don't know of. What I would do:
On the login screen select the cogwheel on the right lower side:
[image: Session menu]

Select "Ubuntu" and not "Ubuntu on Wayland"

Go into your Nvidia Settings and setup that second monitor. It generates an Xorg File that should be copied to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`.

Restart and check if it works